# AMPPS (Mac OS) localhost is unable to run CakePHP 3.2.5. It isn't loading the correct php ini

Tags: php, macos, apache, cakephp, ampps

I'm running the latest AMPPS with PHP 5.6 on my Mac (OS X El Capitan), and trying to run a CakePHP web app. When I run "composer install" under the web app's directory using Terminal, it returns the following errors:

- Problem 1

  - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.5].
  - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system. Problem 2
  - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  - cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.7 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 <4.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.5].
  - Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.7 -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[3.2.7].

---

Then, I opened the php.ini under "/Applications/AMPPS/php/etc/" and found that all the extension are already un-commented.

I then run "php --ini", here is the outcome:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
- Loaded Configuration File: (none)
- Scan for additional .ini files in: /Library/Server/Web/Config/php
- Additional .ini files parsed: (none)

---

I then checked /etc, and changed the "php.ini.default" file to "php.ini".
Downloaded php_intl.dll and moved to "etc/ext", and changed the extension_dir to "/etc/ext".
After that, I restarted AMPPS's Apache and ran "composer install" again, and it returned the followings:

- PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/php_intl.dll' - dlopen(./ext/php_intl.dll, 9): image not found
  in Unknown on line 0 Loading composer repositories with package
  information Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock
  file Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
  packages. Problem 1

  - Installation request for cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.5].
  - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system. Problem 2
  - cakephp/cakephp 3.2.5 requires ext-intl * -> the requested PHP extension intl is missing from your system.
  - cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.7 requires cakephp/cakephp >=3.1.0 <4.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.2.5].
  - Installation request for cakephp/debug_kit 3.2.7 -> satisfiable by cakephp/debug_kit[3.2.7].

---

I have tried running phpinfo(); and the loading path is different from the ones I got in Terminal:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/etc
- Loaded Configuration File /Applications/AMPPS/php/etc/php.ini
- Scan this dir for additional .ini files /Applications/AMPPS/php-5.6/etc/php.d

---

"http://localhost/ampps/" is working.

---

Anyone has any idea why is this happening?